# How do I make a square when the existing edge is not alined to any of the axes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, vertices, coordinates

If I have two arbitrary points (not aligned with any particular axis), is there a way to make a square using them?

For example, if I have two points along the X axis, I can select the edge between them, <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude it, <kbd>Y</kbd> to constrain, and type in the length to make a square.

[image: two points]

[image: extruded square]

Can anyone help me do this if the points are not alined on the X or Y axis?

Comment: double press the axis letter. That will make it move along the local normal.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise: this seems to constrain me to the local x (or y or z) axis, not the normal direction to the two points.

Comment: I meant local/normal, sorry. There is a setting at the bottom of the viewport to change which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the edge selected open up the properties pane with <kbd>N</kbd> Scroll down to the *Mesh display* section and turn on *Length* for the *Edge Info*.

Now press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, then press <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to [constrain](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Axis_Locking) the movement to the Y [*Normal* axis](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations#Normal). Pressing <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> would lock movement to each their respective axes. Finally before you confirm the movement, type in the length of the first edge.